# How far away do you have to be for mobs to spawn

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I have a world in Minecraft PE that only has a tiny island I live on. I want to know how far away do you have to be for mobs to spawn and what light level does it have to be?

Comment: I believe light level is 7+  for mobs to **not** spawn, and for distance 30 blocks comes to mind, but that's pretty much just a guess. The Minecraft wiki will probably have all the information needed.

Answer (score 1):

The distance for mobs to spawn is from 24 to 128 blocks away from any player. Further than that, the mobs don't spawn at all. If you're between 24 and 32 blocks, mobs could spawn and despawn too, probably a memory limit thing. Light level must be lower than 8.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Light